# How do I remove the previous question printed when iterating through a loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, printing

I'm trying to remove the previous line that prints every time I ask, I've tried many different methods such as *'end="\r"* and importing os to try clear the screen, but both fail to work. So, how should I approach this?

I'm using Python 3.8.6

Here is my code. Most of the bottom half isn't relevant here, only everything in cubeCalc()

```
def cubeCalc(a):
    listOfValues = ['height', 'width', 'depth']
    listOfNo = []
    if a == 1:
        for i in range(len(listOfValues)):
            listOfNo.append(int(input("Input the "+str(listOfValues[i])+"(cm): ")))
        print("The volume is",listOfNo[0]*listOfNo[1]*listOfNo[2],"cm³")
        print("The total surface area is",(listOfNo[0]*listOfNo[2])*6,"cm²")
    elif a == 2:
        pass
    
    
def pyramidCalc():
    pass

#main

selection = int(input("Input your selection. 1 for cubes. 2 for pyramids: "))

if selection == 1:
    whichDimension = int(input("Calculations for 3d (1) or 2d (2) shape?: "))
    cubeCalc(whichDimension)
elif selection == 2:
    pyramidCalc()
```

Here is what happens when I run:

[image]

Here is a rough imagining of what I'd like:

[image]

Any other critique you may have of my code is much appreciated. I am not very math inclined so if I could cut down on lines in anyway with better calculations, feel free to add.

Comment: So, you want to clear the previous line? I think that works only in Jupyter Notebook

Comment: @PCM Oh, I might have to look that up. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by clearing the previous line here. Is there a loop in the main body of the code?

Comment: @Mortz I probably should've worded the question better here, so my bad. Every time the user answers a question, (e.g. "Input the height: 5") I want that line to be removed, then replaced with the new question (e.g. "Input the width: "). Hopefully that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `print` is the right tool for that.

You could consider `sys.stdout.write` along with `sys.stdout.flush` instead.

Example:

```
import sys
import time
sys.stdout.write("first text\r")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(1)
sys.stdout.write("second text")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clear your screen after each input:

```
import os

for i in range(len(listOfValues)):
            listOfNo.append(int(input("Input the "+str(listOfValues[i])+"(cm): ")))
        os.system('cls')
        print("The volume is",listOfNo[0]*listOfNo[1]*listOfNo[2],"cm³")
        print("The total surface area is",(listOfNo[0]*listOfNo[2])*6,"cm²")
```

Use `clear` instead of `cls` if you're on Linux.